# How do I restart the program again when the MCU crash occurs.[microchip ATSAMG55J19 ]

Tags: microchip, atmel

I am designing a custom PCB based on the ATSAMG55J19 microcontroller.

I am using the SWD interface with Atmel ICE.

My MCU crashes and stops running code sometimes.
Even if I modified the code and circuit, I did not figure out the problem.
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Question 1:

How do I restart the program again when the MCU crash occurs.
My MCU crashed or stopped randomly by showing the voltage of the NRST LOW. (The NRST signal is LOW constantly and I did not push the reset button).
When the MCU crash occurs, how do I re-initialize the program?
Do I have to modify the Reset_Handler code?

Question 2:

Did I connect the NRST PIN correctly?
Here is the link of the schematic checklist. ( See 1.1.2 64-pin LQFP packages)

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-42392-SAM-G55-Schematic-Checklist_ApplicationNote_AT07216.pdf

My circuit is as below.

[image: Voltage regulator and MCU]

Comment: read about [watchdogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) and supervisory circuits.

Comment: I am a newbie. But I will read the watchdog document and sample program. Thank you.

Comment: A watchdog is an independent counter that the user program must reset periodically before it reaches the counter end. if the user program crashes, or somehow forgets to reset the counter, it counts to the end and automatically resets the whole chip. many microcontrollers have a watchdog timer built-in. you have to read about that in the datasheet to find out how to enable, set its maximum duration or reset it.

Comment: Better to find the reason WHY the program crashes than find to workaround with the watchdog.